# How to simplify this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In reports.rb, I have:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :elements
```

In elements.rb, I have:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :reports
```

The following method works, but it seems longer than it should be:

```
@elements = []
Element.all.each do |element|
  @elements << element if element.reports.empty?
end
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work as there is no reports column:

```
@element = Element.where(reports.empty?)
```

Unfortunately, all the words I've tried punching into the Rails API references — find, etc — are so generic that I can't find a method that works that way that you can see I when `where` to work. Is there one? Or is there some other way I can simplify this method?

Comment: Not a solution, but a more idiomatic way to express that loop would be something like  `@elements = Element.all.select { |element| element.reports.empty? }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be:

```
@elements = Element.all.keep_if {|e| e.reports.empty?}
```

Comment: This will end up being much slower than doing all the work in the DB. You might not notice any difference in development, but populate a couple of (or a few tens of) thousand elements with associated reports, and do some benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. In this case it's all for the admin area for the app, which I alone will use, so I'm not too stressed about response times. But I'll certainly look at doing this at the DB level if it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one way to do this in a low-level way.

```
Element
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN element_reports")
  .group("elements.id")
  .having("element_reports.id IS NULL")
```

This at least pushes the responsibility for filtering to the DB, instead of fetching all the records. This should be a win especially if there are many records, or if they are particularly fat.

Comment: Could be my slow Monday morning brain failing here, but coudn't the `having` clause be a `where`?

Comment: Yep, then we could eliminate the group, too. :-)